# SQL Issue - ODBC Connection

Tags: sql, oracle, sysdate

At the moment we have a line that pulls the ship date of our orders from the system:

```
and o.actualshipdate like sysdate
```

Sysdate is the systematical date of all shipped orders on the current date.

How can we change it or adjust to make it show the orders shipped on the current systematical date but in a certain time frame:

The query works with the following line but we would have to adjust the date everyday. We would like to have this automated for the current date.

Below line needs to be adjusted:

```
and to_char(o.actualshipdate, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI') between '20171220 13:00' and '20171220 13:00'
```

Comment: Every DBMS I know of has some kind of function to return today's date. Like `NOW()` or `TODAY()`. Since you didn't specify what you are using (Oracle? MSSQL? MySQL?) I cannot be any more specific.

Comment: Hello, am using Oracle.

Comment: ***Do Not Convert Dates To Strings***.  Use the inbuilt date data types and functions.

Answer (score 2):

In oracle, we have `sysdate` to provide the current system date. [Check doc for sysdate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm)

If you want a query to get the last 5 hrs shipment details the condition should look like

```
and shipmentdate >= (sysdate-(5/24))
```

If you want last 5 mins then

```
and shipmentdate >= (sysdate-(5/1440))
```

where 1440 = 24*60.

If you want for the last 1 day then

```
and shipmentdate >= sysdate-1
```

Hope you got the idea..

Please note that all this will work only if the shipmentdate is a date datatype column. Otherwise the query will change a little bit.

---

Also you can use between if you want a time-frame for eg.

```
and shipmentdate between (sysdate-(10/24)) and (sysdate-(5/24))
```

And if your shipmentdate can have future records then for all the above conditions use

```
and shipmentdate between sysdate-x and sysdate
```

Comment: On the assumption that there can't be any shipments in the future, you only need `>= sysdate-(5/24)`

Comment: Yup you are correct. Thank you! I will adjust my answer.

Comment: But what about if I have a set time i.e. if I need shipments between 16:00 and 17:30 ?

Comment: Try this .. `select trunc(sysdate)+16/24 , trunc(sysdate)+17.5/24 from dual`.. So the query is `and shipmentdate between trunc(sysdate)+16/24 and trunc(sysdate)+17.5/24` today(system-date) .. `Trunc(date)` will remove its time component.

Comment: @PD1978US - If you don't like calculating the hours as fractions of a day, you can use `SYSDATE + INTERVAL '17:30' HOUR TO MINUTE` : https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals